# Exception guarantee for vector multiple objects constructor

Tags: c++11, vector

When calling this vector constructor:

```
vector( size_type count,
         const T& value,
         const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

If exception will be thrown and some T objects will be already constructed but not all of them, will constructed elements always gets destructor called?

```
 std::vector<std::vector<T>> internalBuffer = 
     std::vector<std::vector<T>>(1024, std::vector<T>(1024, 0));
```

I'm assuming default allocator and c++11.

Answer (score 1):

Note: that particular constructor was removed from C++11.

Other than that, you are correct that the destructors of all the already constructed objects will be called in this case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I edited question. Is there any note from standard that all destructors will be called?